# Transform Raster File to tif File Using GDAL Library

Tags: java, gis, tiff, gdal

I am very new to GIS data and GDAL Library. I am trying to transform .GRC/.GRD file into a .tif file. So that I can read pixels and plot that in any map. My main aim is to read raster and plot that image in any Map. I tried to convert it into image by following code.

```
    String grcFile = "E:\\Reproject.grc";
    gdal.AllRegister();
    Driver tiffDriver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff");
    Dataset dataset = gdal.Open(grcFile, 0);

    Dataset tiffDataset = tiffDriver.CreateCopy("D:\\img.tif", dataset);
```

Here I'm getting the output file `img.tif` but that was corrupted I can't open that using Windows Photo Viewer. Am I doing anything wrong in the code.

Note : I'm also getting one XML file (`img.tif.aux.xml`) as the output which has all area details in .GRC file.

Comment: It is very possible that the image cannot be opened in Windows Photo Viewer without being corrupted. What is the datatype (Float32, Byte, ..) How Many bands are in the image? Try to investigate the new image (print some pixel values).

Comment: How can I read pixels or Lat Lon from .GRC File?

Answer (score -1):

Unless you specifically need to use the GDAL tool, maybe have a look at a piece of software called FME workbench offered here at:

https://www.safe.com/convert/tiff/geotiff/.

Its a far more user friendly way of converting raster data types. You can view ALL datatypes supported by FME inside the client so you don't need to worry about corruption or compatibility with Windows Photo Viewer!

Comment: May I also suggest @Mdumanoj that you ask this question over at **gis.stackexchange** as well. There is a far larger gdal/raster data community on that platform since its specialized!